# Using Adobe Photoshop Gradients to Create Gradients in WPF

Tags: wpf, photoshop, gradient

I am trying to create the same look for my screen as it appears in the image below.

[Desired Look](http://i1234.photobucket.com/albums/ff418/sophiya_raphel/PhotoShop%20Gradient%20Question/Grad1.png)

My designer has given me a PSD file and the gradient overlay in PSD file looks like this.

[PhotoShop Gradient](http://s1234.photobucket.com/albums/ff418/sophiya_raphel/PhotoShop%20Gradient%20Question/)

The color information of each gradient stop is also given at the above link.

I have spent hours trying to create the same look in WPF (sorry, i am a newbee :( ), But no luck yet? Is there a way to directly import photoshop gradients into Blend/VS2010? If not what is the best way of replicating this effect?

thanks in advance,
Sophie

Comment: You should be able to at least approximate the same results in WPF, especially given the gradient stops. Could you please post the XAML of the resulting `LinearGradientBrush` so we can compare it to the target Photoshop settings? Welcome to SO. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In WPF you need more stops for this i think, here would be an approximation i just made:

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFB" Offset="0.027"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.957"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDCDAE4" Offset="0.547"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF1F1F1" Offset="0.47"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF979797"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFDADADA" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

[image: A screenshot]

---

Refined it a bit more since the colour at the bottom becomes lighter again, so now it's 7 stops:

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.03"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.944"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE0DFE5" Offset="0.539"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF1F1F1" Offset="0.47"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9D9CA0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBED" Offset="0.987"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF0F0F2" Offset="1"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

---

What the Blend Gradient Eyedropper (thanks to Kris for mentioning its existence) created:

```
<LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
    <GradientStop Color="#FF9E9DA1" Offset="0.002"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF7F7F7" Offset="0.028"/>
    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.035"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFF1F1F3" Offset="0.472"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFE0DFE5" Offset="0.543"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFFAFAFB" Offset="0.952"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBED" Offset="0.989"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

Comment: Nice. Did you do that in Blend, or just bust it out by hand? :)

Comment: Used Blend, doing that without immediate visual feedback would be a pain.

Comment: That's what I figured. I really need to bug my IT dept. to confirm I can have a Blend license...

Comment: Blend has a Gradient Eyedropper, set a Gradient as a brush then drag to select.

Comment: @Kris: Oh, you're right, it totally did not notice that icon, i tried to use the normal eyedropper before which did not work so i gave up on that.

Comment: Thanks H.B. It looks perfect. I was hoping there was a tool to convert photoshop gradients to WPF gradients. Thanks a lot